# How to save an ArrayList, a custom adapter (and its data) in Android using JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have an Android project that uses a `ListView` displaying a custom object's data from an adapter. I want to save this data when it opens the next time, but I don't know how to parse a custom adapter into JSON, or if I even should, but not doing that makes me thinking of errors. How do I save these data?

`CustomAdapter` that holds objects inside and displays every object in the `ListView` by item.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to persist this data. You could do so by using SQLite or SharedPreferences.
If you are keen on serializing data to a JSON object, you could use a library such as GSON before you eventually use SharedPreferences:
[Check out this medium article, it seems almost exactly what you might need.](https://medium.com/better-programming/flutter-how-to-save-objects-in-sharedpreferences-b7880d0ee2e4)

Answer (score 0):

You have everything explained here. https://www.dev2qa.com/android-sharedpreferences-save-load-java-object-example/.

Convert your object to JSON string and that's it

Answer (score 0):

Well saving the adapter is not how it works, instead, you have to save your list using SharedPrefrences(in this case Gson library will be needed to serialize your data), SQLite, or Room database and next time the app comes to foreground you read your saved data.